# how to android recyclerview change different holder view background

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

[image]

The picture is when I clicked 1.

I want to change the background of other items when clicking the recyclerview item

But looking at my code and thinking, I can't change other holder items when I click the itemview

I did a Google search, but I couldn't find an answer because I couldn't find the right keyword.

It would be a great help if you give me an answer

first my recyclerview Adapter

```
class GiftShowCategoryAdapterHolder(parent: ViewGroup) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_giftshow_category, parent, false)
    ) {
        fun onBind(item: ArrayList<GiftCardResponse.brandCategories>, viewModel: GiftShowViewModel?, position: Int, holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder) {
            itemView.run {
                val displaymetrics = DisplayMetrics()
                (context as Activity).windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displaymetrics)
                val devicewidth: Int = displaymetrics.widthPixels / 4
                val deviceheight: Int = displaymetrics.heightPixels / 8

                itemView.iv_giftshow_category.layoutParams.width = devicewidth
                itemView.iv_giftshow_category.layoutParams.height = deviceheight

                Glide.with(this).load(item[position].categoryIcon).error(R.drawable.choice_cash)
                    .into(iv_giftshow_category)

                tv_giftshow_category.text = item[position].categoryName

                this.background = context.getDrawable(R.drawable.shape_gray_gift_recycler_stroke)

                setOnClickListener {
                    for(i in 0 until item.size){
                        if(i == position){
                            Timber.d("Checked i $i , position $position")
                            linear_background.background = context.getDrawable(R.drawable.shape_white_gift_recycler_stroke)
                            //it.background = context.getDrawable(R.drawable.shape_white_gift_recycler_stroke)
                        }else{
                            Timber.d("Checked else i $i , position $position")
                        }
                    }
                    viewModel?.getBrandItemsResult(item[position].categorySeq)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private var giftShowCategoryList = ArrayList<GiftCardResponse.brandCategories>()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) = GiftShowCategoryAdapterHolder(parent);

    override fun getItemCount() = giftShowCategoryList.size

    private var viewModel: GiftShowViewModel? = null

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        (holder as? GiftShowCategoryAdapterHolder)?.onBind(giftShowCategoryList, viewModel, position, holder)
    }

    fun addItem(items: List<GiftCardResponse.brandCategories>) {
        giftShowCategoryList = items as ArrayList<GiftCardResponse.brandCategories>
    }

    fun addViewModel(viewModel: GiftShowViewModel) {
        this.viewModel = viewModel
    }
```

Comment: what are you trying to say is if you click on particular item the clicked item background should be change right ??

Comment: No, this is the other view you clicked on

Comment: What do you mean by "how to android recyclerview change different holder view background"

Comment: can u plz explain it well so i can understand what exactly you want to achieve..

Comment: A visual representation of what you want to achieve might be helpful

Comment: added a picture !

Comment: Noah // yes , my question is the same as your answer

Comment: no brother u cant change the other views. you only can change the clicked item

Comment: D_K // I've seen similar behavior in other apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put oldPosition and newPosition in the adapter, compare it with the current position, pass the click event to the viewmodel, observe the viewmodel livedata, and replace the data with only the corresponding value in the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on you onBindViewHolder Method:

```
    if(position == selected){
        holder.layout.setBackground(mContext.getDrawable(R.drawable.selected_layout));
    }else {
        holder.layout.setBackground(mContext.getDrawable(R.drawable.layout_background));
    }


    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            selected = holder.getAdapterPosition();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 if((position % 2 == 0)){
       holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(R.color.list_even_color);
 }else{
     holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(R.color.list_odd_color);
}
```

Comment: If you answer this, you will know that only the holder you have is changing.